# SQL: add column which is the division of every to cells

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which reflects the cache hit rate, from the form:

```
Action | logic name | count
 PUSH       a          123
 HIT        a           57
 PUSH       b          321
 HIT        b           77
 PUSH       c          111
 HIT        c           50
```

The hit rate of a is 57/123, of b is 77/321.

The action column has 2 values:
PUSH: the instruction was pushed to the cache and wasn't used
HIT: the instruction was pushed to the cache and was used

The logic name refers to the algorithm name that decides which instruction to push. The count is how many instructions were pushed or hit.

I'm struggling to find a way to add another column which indicates the hit rate of each algorithm. how can it be done?

To make it clear, I would like to see something like this:

```
Action | logic name | count | hit rate %
 PUSH       a          123    46.3
 HIT        a           57    46.3
 PUSH       b          321    23.9
 HIT        b           77    23.9
 PUSH       c          111    45.0
 HIT        c           50    45.0
```

Comment: You have tagged 2 db, `mysql` and `sql-server` and  second one with exact version which more looks like that do you use `sql-server`. So, probably you need to remove  `mysql`  tag ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have exactly 1 row per action per logic name then you can write an inner query like this:

```
SELECT a.action, a.logic_name, a.count, 
((SELECT count FROM table WHERE logic_name = a.logic_name AND action = 'HIT')/ 
 (SELECT count FROM table WHERE logic_name = a.logic_name AND action = 'PUSH'))*100 
AS hit_rate
FROM table a;
```

Comment: what 'a' stand for?

Comment: @AndreyIsakov updated the answer. `a` is an alias for table `hit_rate`

Comment: @DarshanMehta `hit_rate` is not a table. :) Alias `a` should be between `table` and `;`.

Comment: @DarshanMehta I know, but I wanted to be sure, that you are going to correct your answer. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

If you have exactly 1 row per action per logic name and Action's are only `HIT` and `PUSH`, then you can use `min()` (or `max()`) window analytic function with condition, something like:

```
select the_table.*, 
min(case when Action = 'HIT' then count end) over(partition by logic_name) / 
min(case when Action = 'PUSH' then count end) over(partition by logic_name) * 100 as hit_rate
from the_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this using `PIVOT`. This solution is more flexible as it works even if you have more than 2 `HIT-PUSH` rows per `logic_name`. The idea is to represent `HIT` and `RATE` as columns per `logic_name`:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ([action] VARCHAR(50), logic_name VARCHAR(50), [count] INT)

INSERT into @t1 ([action], logic_name, [count]) VALUES 
    ('PUSH','a',123)
    ,('HIT','a',57)
    ,('PUSH','b',321)
    ,('HIT','b',77) ;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [logic_name]
          ,[PUSH]
          ,[HIT]
          ,(CAST ([HIT] AS DECIMAL)/[PUSH]) AS HitRate
    FROM (
                SELECT [action]
                       ,[logic_name]
                        ,[count]
                FROM @t1
         ) AS Source
    PIVOT
    (
     SUM([count])
    FOR [action] IN ([PUSH],[HIT])
    ) AS PivotTable
)
SELECT tt.*,c.HitRate
FROM @t1 tt
JOIN cte c ON c.logic_name = tt.logic_name
```